# update vuejs list item in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

vuejs 2.x.

I have `a.html` which looks like:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" v-for="ec in eb.ecustomerList">

    <label >{{ec.customerTypeName}}</label>

    <div class="form-inline">

        <input type="text" class="form-control customerSearchInput" v-bind:id="ec.customerTypeName"
                            style="width: 20%">&nbsp;&nbsp; 

       <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg customerSearchIcon" style="color: blue" ></i>

      <input type="hidden" v-bind:id="ec.customerTypeName+'Id'" v-model="ec.customerId"  />

      <input type="hidden" v-model="ec.customerType" value="3" />
  </div>

  <textarea id="shipperText" v-model="ec.customerDetail"></textarea>

</div>

  <div id="bHtml"></div>
```

the `v-model="ec.customerId"` has to be set in `b.html` like

```
function selectCustomer(id, item) {

        $("#"+id).val(item.name);
        $("#"+id+"Id").val(item.id);
        $("#"+id+"Text").val(item.otherName);
        //need to update value of v-model="ec.customerId" here
    }
```

and the `b.html` will loaded to `<div id="bHtml"></div>` of `a.html`.

For some reasons, I cannot add `selectCustomer(id, item)` to vue instance.

So in this case, how can I update the list item of vue model in js function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comply with the standards of Vuejs you need to include the *selectCustomer* function in the *methods* of vuejs and call the method accordingly where you need to change it from. Instead of having selectCustomer as a separate js function. Also have the contents on b.html directly inside the `<div id="bHtml"></div>` and change the value through the *selectCustomer* method. Like so

> ```
> template:
> `<div class="form-group col-md-4" v-for="ec in eb.ecustomerList"> 
>   // rest of the html 
> </div> 
> <div id="bHtml">  
>    <div> selected name {{item.name}}</div>  
>    <div> selected id {{item.id}}</div>  
>    <div> selected text {{item.otherName}}</div>   
> </div>`,
>
> data: function(){  
>   return{    
>     item:{name:'', id:'', otherName:''}  
>   }
> }, 
> methods:{  
>    selectCustomer: function(id, item, vModel) {
>         $("#"+id).val(item.name);
>         $("#"+id+"Id").val(item.id);
>         $("#"+id+"Text").val(item.otherName);
>
>         //update the vmodel as required
>         vModel = newValue;
>     } 
>  }
> ```

You need to understand that Vuejs changes your application according to the reactive data change method. Instead of using jQuery to manipulate the html DOM.